# is there any solution when insert json data it gives .length error in node js?

Tags: node.js, postman

[![what actually im passing in this form and give me and error .length of undefined ][1]][1]

*it give an error in for loop **.length** of undefined in node js when is pass api in postman it give and .length of undefined error how can i solve it? *

````
app.post('/sub',function(req,res,next)
{
  var data = req.body;
  var values = [];
  var data1 = data.length;
  for(var i=0; i< data1; i++)
  values.push([data[i].subaction,data[i].mapped_flow_id,data[i].flow_name,data[i].function_id]);
  conn.query('INSERT INTO flow(subaction,mapped_flow_id,flow_name,function_id) VALUES ?', [values], function(err,result) {
    if(err) {
      res.send('Error');
    }
    else {
       res.send({ status: false, data:result, message: 'Success' });
    }
  });
});```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsFPX.png
````

Comment: what is the data in req.body ? can you show what are you posting

Comment: to store database field data to use req.body.

Comment: it should be an array !Check it once.

Comment: [
 {
  "subaction":"abc",
  "mapped_flow_id":"1",
  "flow_name":"abcdef",
  "function_id":"1"
  
 },
 {
  "subaction":"frgh",
  "mapped_flow_id":"2",
  "flow_name":"ewwerw",
  "function_id":"2"
 }
] in this form and yes array

Comment: yes in array form

Comment: can you check this once and tell what type are you getting ?  console.log(typeof data)

Comment: it gives me undefined

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in posting your data.!

Comment: i can share image in my question and also show what data i am posting

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsFPX.png

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
app.post('/sub',function(req,res,next)
{
  var data =[];
data= req.body;
  var values = [];
  var data1 = data.length;
  for(var i=0; i< data1; i++)
  values.push([data[i].subaction,data[i].mapped_flow_id,data[i].flow_name,data[i].function_id]);
  conn.query('INSERT INTO flow(subaction,mapped_flow_id,flow_name,function_id) VALUES ?', [values], function(err,result) {
    if(err) {
      res.send('Error');
    }
    else {
       res.send({ status: false, data:result, message: 'Success' });
    }
  });
});
```